# How to send data from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

hi all i am new to android development my question is that how to call input edit text data in any activity where i required just like local storage in hmtl5  how to set value and get them where i required in any activity but not in the intent activity where i mentioned in the below example i want to show in some other activity means i need to get the values

here is my code

```
public class Autoinput extends Activity {

EditText Engines, Drivers;

Button next;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.autoinputvalues);

    Engines = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noofengines);
    Drivers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noofdrivers);


    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.autoinputnext);

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent autoinputscreen = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),       autocoverage.class);
            startActivity(autoinputscreen);
        }
    });

}
```

}

if we write put extra in intent it will go to that particular activity which we mention intent and there only we can get it my intention is to call in any activity and show them.

Comment: please be clear with your question

Comment: So if you want store your value you can use shared preference.

Comment: read my answer to do that

Answer (score 0):

if you want save your data and required in any activity must use Database or Share preference

To obtain shared preferences, use the following method In your activity:

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 Vboolean IsTurnOn = preferences.getBoolean("Key", Default_Value);
```

To edit and set preferences

```
 Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("Key", Value);
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be destroyed after your application is closed or crashed you can use something like global variables: For example refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/611985/Global-Variable-in-Android)

On the other hand if you want your data to be persisted even after application crash, you can use shared preferences:

```
 SharedPreferences pref;
 pref=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
 editor=pref.edit();
```

**Set data:**

```
editor.putString("Engines", Engines.getText().toString());
editor.putString("Drivers", Drivers.getText().toString());
```

**Then retrieve from anywhere:**

```
 String engines=pref.getString(("Engines",null);
 String drivers=pref.getString(("Drivers",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use shared preference. You should refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways, one is using Bundle and the another one throught Intent.

Using **Bundle**,

To Send:

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Key", "Value");
passIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(passIntent);
```

To Receive:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String recText = bundle.getString("Key");
```

Using Through **Intent**:

To Send:

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
passIntent.putExtras("Key", "Value");
startActivity(passIntent);
```

To Receive:

```
String recText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key");
```

For your Code, in your FirstActivity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
                    Intent passIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    passIntent.putExtras("Key", position);
                    startActivity(passIntent);
                }
            });
```

In SecondActivity,

```
details.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key"));
```